# How to automate selecting certain codes in an html?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, dom, automation

Hi I have a question about automating selecting certain content in an HTML. So if we **save an webpage as html only**, then we'll get HTML codes along with other stylesheets and javascript codes. However, I only want to extract the HTML codes between `<div class='post-content' itemprop='articleBody'>`and`</div>` and then create a new HTML file that has the extracted HTML codes. Is there a possible way to do it? Example codes are down below:

```
<html>
<script src='.....'>
</script>
<style>
...
</style>
<div class='header-outer'>
<div class='header-title'>
<div class='post-content' itemprop='articleBody'>
<p>content we want</p>
</div>
</div></div>
<div class='footer'>
</div>
</html>
```

While I'm typing, I'm thinking about javascript, which seems to be able to manipulate HTML DOM elements..Is Ruby able to do that? Can I generate a new clean html that only contains content between `<div class='post-content' itemprop='articleBody'>`and`</div>` by using javascript or Ruby? However, as for how to write the actual code, I don't have a clue.

So anybody has any idea about it? Thank you so much!

Comment: what is source of html and use case?

Comment: example html: view-source:https://googleblog.blogspot.com/  Please don't **inspect the element**, but **view the source** or **save the webpage as HTML only** instead. Not sure about what to say about the use case...but I need just the content between those tags mentioned above which contains the blog content...Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't explain much as to what you are trying to do. There are numerous ways to do what you are asking and approach would depend on use case

Comment: Hey just edited my question. Does that clarify the use case?

Comment: A ID tag on the selected content might be useful, or have an XML reader to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I'll take a crack at it.

> Can Ruby modify the DOM on a webpage?

Short answer, no. Browsers don't know how to run Ruby. They do know how to run javascript, so that's what usually used for real-time DOM manipulation.

> Can I generate a new clean html

Yes? At the end of the day, HTML is just a specifically formatted string. If you want to download the source from that page and find everything in the `<div class='post-content' itemprop='articleBody'>` tag, there are a couple of ways to go about that. The best is probably the `nokogiri` gem, which is a ruby HTML parser. You'll be able to feed it a string (from a file or otherwise) that represents the old page and strip out what you want. Doing that would look something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://googleblog.blogspot.com"))
# finds the first child of the <div class="post-content"> element
text = page.css('.post-content')[0].text
```

I believe that gives you the text you're looking for. More detailed nokogiri instructions can be found [here](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at Nokogiri documentation and see if I can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a regular expression. For example:

```
//The "m" means multi-line
var regEx = /<div class='post-content' itemprop='articleBody'>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/m;

//The content (you'll put the javascript at the bottom
var bodyCode = document.body.innerHTML;

var match = bodyCode.match( regEx );

//Prints to the console
console.dir( match );
```

You can see this in action here: https://regex101.com/r/kJ5kW6/1

Comment: Thank you Don. That's a good idea...but how should I later extract the content I want and write them into a new HTML?

Comment: @Penny I'm not going to do this entirely for you (what's the fun in that?) but what you can do is copy what's printed out in the console and use that in your new HTML page.

Comment: Hi Don, my intention is to automate the whole process...If copy-and-paste the code I want into a new HTML page, I certainly can do that and I dont even need to use the Regex. However, it's not realistic to do that in bulk...

Comment: @Penny if you want to automate it, still use the regular expression but use php (you'll run this in an Apache web server) and load the web page you want via `curl` and take that content and feed it to your regular expression